# Annotating with Count not working how I expect it to

Tags: django

I'm experimenting with Django by building a simple RPG. It has armor upgrades. There are different categories of armor (e.g. head and body). Each category has many pieces of armor. For example, the "Head" category might have "Dragon Helm", "Duck Helm", "Needle Helm", and others.

In order for the user to see *any* of the armor available in the a category, they must first be granted access to at least one of the pieces of armor in that category. At that point, they can *view* all of the armor in that category—including the armor they can't yet purchase.

### The Problem

I'm trying to *efficiently* query the database for all of a category's armor while simultaneously taking note of which pieces of armor the user has been granted access to. I have it kind of working, but not totally.

### Relevant code

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Armor(models.Model):
    armor_category = models.ForeignKey('ArmorCategory')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', through='ProfileArmor')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class ArmorCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Armor categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    dob = models.DateField('Date of Birth')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()


class ProfileArmor(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    armor = models.ForeignKey(Armor)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.profile.user.get_full_name(), self.armor.name)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from core import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^upgrades/(?P<armor_category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.Upgrades.as_view(), name='upgrades'),
)
```

**views.py** (this file is where the problem is)

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .models import ArmorCategory


class Upgrades(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'core/upgrades.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make sure the slug is valid.

        self.armor_category = get_object_or_404(ArmorCategory, slug=kwargs['armor_category_slug'])

        # Make sure the user has been granted access to at least one item in
        # this category, otherwise there is no point for the user to even be
        # here.

        if self.armor_category.armor_set.filter(
            profilearmor__profile=self.request.user.profile
        ).count() == 0:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        return super(Upgrades, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS.

        # Get all of the armor in this category, but also take note of which
        # armor this user has been granted access to.

        armor = self.armor_category.armor_set.filter(
            Q(profilearmor__profile=self.request.user.profile) |
            Q(profilearmor__profile=None)
        ).annotate(profile_armor_count=Count('profilearmor__id'))

        print armor.query

        for armor_item in armor:
            print '%s: %s' % (armor_item.name, armor_item.profile_armor_count)

        return {
            'armor_category': self.armor_category,
            'armor': armor,
        }
```

### More Details of the Problem

I created the "Head" category and gave it the three pieces of armor indicated in the first paragraph of this question. I created the armor in the same order I have them listed above. I then created two user profiles.

I gave the first user profile access to the "Duck Helm" armor. I then accessed /upgrades/head/ with the first user profile and got this output from the `for` loop:

```
Dragon Helm: 0
Duck Helm: 1
Needle Helm: 0
```

This was the expected output. Next, I gave the second user profile access to the "Dragon Helm" armor. When I accessed the same URL with the second user profile, I got this output:

```
Dragon Helm: 1
Needle Helm: 0
```

Why isn't the "Duck Helm" armor listed? I decided to go back to the same URL with the first user profile again to make sure it was still working. When I did that, I got this output:

```
Duck Helm: 1
Needle Helm: 0
```

Now the "Dragon Helm" armor was gone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### 1. Quick explanation

When you test a many-to-many relation against `None` in a Django queryset, as you do here:

```
Q(profilearmor__profile=None)
```

that matches rows where there are *no* corresponding rows in the many-to-many relation. So your query

```
self.armor_category.armor_set.filter(
    Q(profilearmor__profile=self.request.user.profile) |
    Q(profilearmor__profile=None))
```

matches items of armor which either the `self.request.user` has access to, or which *no-one* has access to. That's why your query for the second user failed to return a row for the Duck Helm: because *someone* (namely the first user) had access to it.

#### 2. What to do instead

The query that you want to run looks like this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT `myapp_armor`.`id`, `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id`, `myapp_armor`.`name`,
       COUNT(`myapp_profilearmor`.`id`) AS `profile_armor_count`
FROM `myapp_armor`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profilearmor`
             ON `myapp_armor`.`id` = `myapp_profilearmor`.`armor_id`
                AND `myapp_profilearmor`.`profile_id` = %s
WHERE `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id` = %s
GROUP BY `myapp_armor`.`id`, `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id`, `myapp_armor`.`name`
```

Unfortunately, Django's object-relational mapping system doesn't seem to provide a way to express this query. But you can always bypass the ORM and issue a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). Like this:

```
sql = '''
    SELECT `myapp_armor`.`id`, `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id`, `myapp_armor`.`name`,
           COUNT(`myapp_profilearmor`.`id`) AS `profile_armor_count`
    FROM `myapp_armor`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profilearmor`
                 ON `myapp_armor`.`id` = `myapp_profilearmor`.`armor_id`
                    AND `myapp_profilearmor`.`profile_id` = %s
    WHERE `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id` = %s
    GROUP BY `myapp_armor`.`id`, `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id`, `myapp_armor`.`name`
'''
armor = Armor.objects.raw(sql, [self.request.user.profile.id, self.armor_category.id])
for armor_item in armor:
    print('{:14}{}'.format(armor_item.name, armor_item.profile_armor_count))
```

For example:

```
>>> helmets = ArmorCategory.objects.get(id=1)
>>> profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1)
>>> armor = Armor.objects.raw(sql, [profile.id, helmets.id])
>>> for armor_item in armor:
...     print('{:14}{}'.format(armor_item.name, armor_item.profile_armor_count))
... 
Dragon Helm   0
Duck Helm     1
Needle Helm   0
```

#### 3. How you could have figured this out for yourself

Here's the offending Django query:

```
armor = self.armor_category.armor_set.filter(
    Q(profilearmor__profile=self.request.user.profile) |
    Q(profilearmor__profile=None)
).annotate(profile_armor_count=Count('profilearmor__id'))
```

When you don't understand why a query is producing the wrong results, it's always worth looking at the actual SQL, which you can do by taking the queryset's `query` attribute and converting it to a string:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> helmets = ArmorCategory.objects.get(name='Helmets')
>>> profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1)
>>> print(helmets.armor_set.filter(Q(profilearmor__profile=profile) |
...                                Q(profilearmor__profile=None)
... ).annotate(profile_armor_count=Count('profilearmor__id')).query)
SELECT `myapp_armor`.`id`, `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id`, `myapp_armor`.`name`,
       COUNT(`myapp_profilearmor`.`id`) AS `profile_armor_count`
FROM `myapp_armor`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profilearmor`
             ON (`myapp_armor`.`id` = `myapp_profilearmor`.`armor_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profile`
             ON (`myapp_profilearmor`.`profile_id` = `myapp_profile`.`id`) 
WHERE (`myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id` = 1
       AND (`myapp_profilearmor`.`profile_id` = 1
            OR `myapp_profile`.`id` IS NULL))
GROUP BY `myapp_armor`.`id`, `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id`, `myapp_armor`.`name`
ORDER BY NULL
```

What does this mean? If you know all about SQL joins, you can skip to section 5. Otherwise, read on.

#### 4. Introduction to SQL joins

As I'm sure you know, a [*join* of tables in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) consists of combinations of rows from those tables (subject to some conditions that you specify in your query). For example, if you have two categories of armor and six items of armor:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myapp_armorcategory;
+----+---------+---------+
| id | name    | slug    |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |
+----+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM myapp_armor;
+----+-------------------+-------------+
| id | armor_category_id | name        |
+----+-------------------+-------------+
|  1 |                 1 | Dragon Helm |
|  2 |                 1 | Duck Helm   |
|  3 |                 1 | Needle Helm |
|  4 |                 2 | Spiky Suit  |
|  5 |                 2 | Flower Suit |
|  6 |                 2 | Battle Suit |
+----+-------------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

then a `JOIN` of those two tables will contain all 12 combinations of the 2 rows from the first table and the 6 rows of the second table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myapp_armorcategory JOIN myapp_armor;
+----+---------+---------+----+-------------------+-------------+
| id | name    | slug    | id | armor_category_id | name        |
+----+---------+---------+----+-------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  1 |                 1 | Dragon Helm |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  1 |                 1 | Dragon Helm |
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  2 |                 1 | Duck Helm   |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  2 |                 1 | Duck Helm   |
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  3 |                 1 | Needle Helm |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  3 |                 1 | Needle Helm |
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  4 |                 2 | Spiky Suit  |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  4 |                 2 | Spiky Suit  |
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  5 |                 2 | Flower Suit |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  5 |                 2 | Flower Suit |
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  6 |                 2 | Battle Suit |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  6 |                 2 | Battle Suit |
+----+---------+---------+----+-------------------+-------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Normally one adds conditions to the join to restrict the rows returned so that they make sense. For example, when joining the armor category table with the armor table we're only interested in combinations where the armor belongs to the armor category:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myapp_armorcategory JOIN myapp_armor
           ON myapp_armorcategory.id = myapp_armor.armor_category_id;
+----+---------+---------+----+-------------------+-------------+
| id | name    | slug    | id | armor_category_id | name        |
+----+---------+---------+----+-------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  1 |                 1 | Dragon Helm |
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  2 |                 1 | Duck Helm   |
|  1 | Helmets | helmets |  3 |                 1 | Needle Helm |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  4 |                 2 | Spiky Suit  |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  5 |                 2 | Flower Suit |
|  2 | Suits   | suits   |  6 |                 2 | Battle Suit |
+----+---------+---------+----+-------------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

This is all straightforward. But a problem arises where there are records in one table that have no matching item in the other. Let's add a new armor category with no corresponding items of armor:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO myapp_armorcategory (name, slug) VALUES ('Arm Guards', 'armguards');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

If we re-run the query above (`SELECT * FROM myapp_armorcategory JOIN myapp_armor ON myapp_armorcategory.id = myapp_armor.armor_category_id;`) we'll get the same result: the new armor category has no matching records in the armor table so it doesn't appear in the `JOIN`. If we want to see all armor categories appear in the results, regardless of whether they have a matching row in the other table, we have to run a so-called [*outer* join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join): in particular a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myapp_armorcategory LEFT OUTER JOIN myapp_armor
           ON myapp_armorcategory.id = myapp_armor.armor_category_id;

+----+------------+-----------+------+-------------------+-------------+
| id | name       | slug      | id   | armor_category_id | name        |
+----+------------+-----------+------+-------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Helmets    | helmets   |    1 |                 1 | Dragon Helm |
|  1 | Helmets    | helmets   |    2 |                 1 | Duck Helm   |
|  1 | Helmets    | helmets   |    3 |                 1 | Needle Helm |
|  2 | Suits      | suits     |    4 |                 2 | Spiky Suit  |
|  2 | Suits      | suits     |    5 |                 2 | Flower Suit |
|  2 | Suits      | suits     |    6 |                 2 | Battle Suit |
|  3 | Arm Guards | armguards | NULL |              NULL | NULL        |
+----+------------+-----------+------+-------------------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For each row in the left-hand table that has no matching rows in the right-hand table, the left outer join contains a row with `NULL` for each column on the right.

#### 5. Explaining why the query goes wrong

Let's create a single profile who has access to the Duck Helm:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO myapp_profile (name) VALUES ('user1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO myapp_profilearmor (profile_id, armor_id) VALUES (1, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then let's run a simplified version of your query to try to understand what it is doing:

```
mysql> SELECT `myapp_armor`.*, `myapp_profilearmor`.*, T5.*
        FROM `myapp_armor`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profilearmor`
                    ON (`myapp_armor`.`id` = `myapp_profilearmor`.`armor_id`)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profile` T5
                    ON (`myapp_profilearmor`.`profile_id` = T5.`id`)
        WHERE `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id` = 1;

+----+-------------------+-------------+------+------------+----------+------+-------+
| id | armor_category_id | name        | id   | profile_id | armor_id | id   | name  |
+----+-------------------+-------------+------+------------+----------+------+-------+
|  1 |                 1 | Dragon Helm | NULL |       NULL |     NULL | NULL | NULL  |
|  2 |                 1 | Duck Helm   |    1 |          1 |        1 |    1 | user1 |
|  3 |                 1 | Needle Helm | NULL |       NULL |     NULL | NULL | NULL  |
+----+-------------------+-------------+------+------------+----------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

So when you add the condition `(myapp_profilearmor.profile_id = 1 OR T5.id IS NULL)` then you'll get all the rows from this join.

Now let's create a second profile with access to the Dragon Helm:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO myapp_profile (name) VALUES ('user2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO myapp_profilearmor (profile_id, armor_id) VALUES (2, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)
```

And re-run the join:

```
mysql> SELECT `myapp_armor`.*, `myapp_profilearmor`.*, T5.*
        FROM `myapp_armor`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profilearmor`
                    ON (`myapp_armor`.`id` = `myapp_profilearmor`.`armor_id`)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `myapp_profile` T5
                    ON (`myapp_profilearmor`.`profile_id` = T5.`id`)
        WHERE `myapp_armor`.`armor_category_id` = 1;

+----+-------------------+-------------+------+------------+----------+------+-------+
| id | armor_category_id | name        | id   | profile_id | armor_id | id   | name  |
+----+-------------------+-------------+------+------------+----------+------+-------+
|  1 |                 1 | Dragon Helm |    2 |          2 |        1 |    2 | user2 |
|  2 |                 1 | Duck Helm   |    1 |          1 |        2 |    1 | user1 |
|  3 |                 1 | Needle Helm | NULL |       NULL |     NULL | NULL | NULL  |
+----+-------------------+-------------+------+------------+----------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now you can see that when you run the query for the second user profile, the extra condition on the join will be `(myapp_profilearmor.profile_id = 2 OR T5.id IS NULL)` and this will select only rows 1 and 3. Row 2 will be missing.

So you can see that your original filter `Q(profilearmor__profile=None)` became the subclause `T5.id IS NULL` and this only selects rows where there is *no* entry (for any profile) in the `ProfileArmor` relation.

#### 6. Other comments on your code

1. You test to see if the profile has access to any type of armor in a category using the [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) method on the queryset:

   ```
   if self.armor_category.armor_set.filter(
       profilearmor__profile=self.request.user.profile
   ).count() == 0:
   ```

   but since you don't actually care about the *number* of types of armor in the category which the profile has access to, just whether there's *any*, you should use the [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method instead.
2. Having gone to the trouble to set up a `ManyToManyField` on the `Armor` model, why not use it? That is, instead of querying the `Armor` model like this:

   ```
   Q(profilearmor__profile = ...)
   ```

   you can run the same query like this and save some typing:

   ```
   Q(profile = ...)
   ```

#### 7. Postscript

This was an excellent question. All too often, Django questions don't provide enough detail of the models, for anyone to be able to answer with confidence.

Comment: Wow. *Phenomenal* answer! Thank you so much for your time and effort! I gave your raw SQL a try and it gave me exactly what I needed! The explanation of joins was definitely appreciated. I also really liked the "Other comments on your code" section. I took your advice. Also, nice work finding the Secret of Mana armor! Lastly, I'm glad my question had enough detail. Thanks again, very much!